# Why Can't I catch up the 'todo' in switch method? ClassList and Style showing Undefined

Tags: javascript, html, styles

So, these are Javascript code.

```js
    const todoFilter = document.querySelector('.filter-todo');
    todoFilter.addEventListener('change', filterTodo);

    function filterTodo(e) {

    const todos = todoList.childNodes;
    
    todos.forEach(function (todo) {
        switch (e.target.value) {
            case "all":
                todo.style.display = "flex";
                break;
            case "completed":
                if (todo.classList.contains("completed")) {    //here classList is undefined
                    todo.style.display = 'flex';               //here style is undefined
                } else {
                    todo.style.display = 'none';               //here style is undefined
                }
                break;
            case "uncompleted":
                if (todo.classList.contains('uncompleted')) { //here ClassList is undefined
                    todo.style.display = 'none';              //here style is undefined
                } else {
                    todo.style.display = 'flex';              //here style is undefined
                }
        }
    });
}
```

And Here HTML:

```
 <form action="">
    <input type="text" class="todo-input">
    <button class="todo-button" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-plus-square" aria-hidden="true">
    </i></button>
    <div class="select">
        <select name="todos" class="filter-todo">
            <option value="all">All</option>
            <option value="completed">Completed</option>
            <option value="uncompleted">Uncompleted</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
<div class="todo-container">
    <div class="todo-list">

    </div>
</div>
<script src="todo.js"></script>
```

These errors are showing in console:

```
todo.style is undefined
todo.classList is undefined
```

Comment: It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details?

Comment: Also, in your code `todoList` doesn't exist. Where is that defined?

Comment: const todoList = document.querySelector('.todo-list');
const todoFilter = document.querySelector('.filter-todo');

Comment: But `todoList` has no childnodes so how can you iterate over them?

Comment: Actually I'm not clear about that. I'm new in Js. I followed a video tutorial.

Comment: when i console `todos` =>` NodeList(5) [ #text, div.todo.completed, div.todo, div.todo, div.todo ]`

Comment: Use `children`, not `childNodes`.

Comment: See [What is the difference between children and childNodes in JavaScript?](/q/7935689/4642212).

Comment: It's working now.(with `childNodes`).I don't why didn't work it yesterday. Thank you all.